# What is my error in a map in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to solve this problem: http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=4, but I cant figure out why my code doesnt solve this, I mean in the "for" how can I can multiply the letters? What is my error? It just tell always 7, but I want to multiple all the letters. I hope you can help me.

```
public class ejercicio3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Map<Character, Integer> telefono = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        telefono.put('A', 2);
        telefono.put('B', 2);
        telefono.put('C', 2);
        telefono.put('D', 3);
        telefono.put('E', 3);
        telefono.put('F', 3);
        telefono.put('G', 4);
        telefono.put('H', 4);
        telefono.put('I', 4);
        telefono.put('J', 5);
        telefono.put('K', 5);
        telefono.put('L', 5);
        telefono.put('M', 6);
        telefono.put('N', 6);
        telefono.put('O', 6);
        telefono.put('P', 7);
        telefono.put('R', 7);
        telefono.put('S', 7);
        telefono.put('T', 8);
        telefono.put('U', 8);
        telefono.put('V', 8);
        telefono.put('W', 9);
        telefono.put('X', 9);
        telefono.put('Y', 9);

        String mensaje = "Practice";
        int producto = 1;

        for (char c : mensaje.toCharArray()) {    
            if (telefono.containsKey(c)) {
                producto = telefono.get(c) * producto;
                System.out.println(producto);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose it's worth pointing out that this would have been easy to debug with just a few print statements. If you'd just printed out the character and the running calculation at each step, it would have been obvious that only 'P' was being counted and when overflow occured.

Answer (score 4):

Convert your string to all uppercase first!

It's only finding the first character, 'P', for which it gives the correct answer of 7.

Try changing:

```
for (char c : mensaje.toCharArray()) {
```

to

```
for (char c : mensaje.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
```

Comment: I did that thanks, but I still get a question what could I do if I have this spaces?

String mensaje = "PROGRAMMING CHALLENGES ARE FUN";

Comment: Well, what do you want to do? Either add a value for spaces to the map or just ignore them (which the code does currently).

Comment: String mensaje = "Programming challenges are fun";
        int producto = 1;

        for (char c : mensaje.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {

            if (telefono.containsKey(c)) {
                producto = telefono.get(c) * producto;
                
            }
        }

         System.out.println(producto);
    }

Comment: Well that looks like overflow. Change "int producto" to "long producto" and see if that helps.

Comment: is there a way to get rid of the spaces in the strings?

Comment: You're not counting them anyway!

Comment: Ok I get it anyway if I just put: String mensaje = "Programming challengesarefun"; I get the same result: -1820327936

Comment: @amweg, because of the condition `if (telefono.containsKey(c)`, you are already ignoring spaces.

Comment: @amveg, tranquilo. Read what both me and Adrian suggested, and change `int` to `long`.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the case-sensitivity problem as suggested in [Adrian Mouat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795076/what-is-my-error-in-a-map-in-java/2795101#2795101), the problem remains that with longer strings the integer overflows pretty soon. Use `long` instead:

```
long producto = 1;
```

(After that e.g. "Programming Challenges are fun" produces 208129028102553600.)

**Edit**: Or, as WineSoaked correctly points out, use [BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to make this support arbitrarily long strings (only the RAM available to JVM is then the limit). But, as we've seen, `long` was good enough for this particular puzzle. :-)

Comment: Good catch on the int overflow.

Comment: In fact, you might end up needing BigInteger, depending on the size of the input string.

Comment: Yes I think so the next time I will think int that

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a case sensitivity issue. That is, "P" is the only character actually found in the map.

If you want to use a mixed-case string, either do `mensaje.toUpperCase().toCharArray()` or add lower case equivalent letters to the map, like `telefono.put('a',2);`